# localhost:3000 unavailable after generating new scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, scaffolding, scaffold

I am new to Rails and I'm following along with a tutorial on Skillshare (http://www.skillshare.com/classes/technology/Ruby-on-Rails-in-30-Days-Build-Your-First-Web-App/).

At the point where I'm generating a new scaffold for a Post, I got all of the correct output from the Terminal.  However, when I went to refresh my localhost:3000 in the browser, I got a message that "This webpage is not available" though I was expecting to get an error message of "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError."  I went ahead and ran db rake anyway, but I still just got the stock "This webpage is not available" message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is what I typed into the terminal.

```
    allison:crumblr aehn83$ rails generate scaffold Post title:string content:text --no-stylesheets
      invoke  active_record
   identical    db/migrate/20141106005237_create_posts.rb
   identical    app/models/post.rb
      invoke    test_unit
   identical      test/models/post_test.rb
   identical      test/fixtures/posts.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :posts
      invoke  scaffold_controller
   identical    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
       exist      app/views/posts
   identical      app/views/posts/index.html.erb
   identical      app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
   identical      app/views/posts/show.html.erb
   identical      app/views/posts/new.html.erb
   identical      app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
      invoke    test_unit
   identical      test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb
      invoke    helper
   identical      app/helpers/posts_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
   identical        test/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb
      invoke    jbuilder
   identical      app/views/posts/index.json.jbuilder
   identical      app/views/posts/show.json.jbuilder
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
```

Comment: did you run the server using `rails s` ??

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then run the server

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran

> db rake

instead of

> rake db:migrate

The error says "pending migration" its talking about migrating the database

Answer (score -1):

sounds like your rails server isn't running.

I usually make the same mistake sometimes when only using one terminal.
Make sure you restart the server with `rails s` after making changes